# A few questions preceding abstract Green's formula theorem

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a linear topological space contained in $V$ and dense in $H$, $V,H,Z$ are Hilbert spaces with $V$ contained in $H$. $H$ is a pivot space ($H=H^*$). Denote by $V_0$ the cloasure of $\mathcal{D}$. Then we have the inclusions 
$$\mathcal{D}\subset V_0\subset H=H^*\subset V_{0}^{*}.$$
The inclusions are dense.

Suppose that $V_{0}$ is the kernel of the surjective map $\gamma\in L(V,Z)$ from $V$ onto $Z$. In one of my books I found the following statement: *there exists $\delta\in L(Z,V)$ such that $\delta \circ\gamma$ is a projection i.e., a continuous linear operator satisfying $(\delta \circ \gamma)^2=(\delta \circ \gamma)$ whose kernel is $V_{0}$ and its transpose (read adjoint) $\gamma^*\circ \delta^*$ is a projection of $V^*$ onto $V_{0}^{\bot}$*.

What's going on? Why such a kernel and projection of $V^*$ onto $V_{0}^{\bot}$?

My considerations are as follows: I know the following theorem: *A mapping $f\colon S\to T$ is surjective if and only if there exists $g\colon T\to S$ such that $f\circ g=I_T$, where $I_T$ is the indentity map on $T$*. So, since $\gamma$ is surjective, there exists right inverse $\delta$ such that $\gamma\circ\delta=I_Z$. If so, one can write $$\gamma\circ\delta=I_Z\iff \delta\circ (\gamma\circ\delta)=\delta\iff (\gamma\circ\delta)\circ (\gamma\circ\delta)=(\gamma\circ\delta)$$
which is very close to what is obtained in the book...

Answer (score 0):

You want to define $\delta$ so that it sends $\gamma(p)$ to a $q$ satisfying $\gamma(q)=\gamma(p)$. (Why does this make $\delta \circ \gamma$ idempotent?) Since $\gamma$ has nontrivial kernel, there are more than one of those. But additionally you want $q$ to be orthogonal to the kernel of $\delta \circ \gamma$. (There are various reasons why you might want this, but in this context it is just a requirement of the statement of the theorem.) Thus $\delta$ can be defined as: $p:=\delta(g)$ is the orthogonal projection of any solution to $\gamma(p)=g$ onto the orthogonal complement of the kernel of $\gamma$.

If that still doesn't make sense, think about the finite dimensional case; this result is not really much different in the infinite dimensional case.